# How to add Char inside a generated data?

Tags: postgresql

I want to insert a char in the middle of a word but the problem is word is generated number the length of the word is not always the same, first I try concat

the word is
`No.SKF.2164-02/2020/CBO-ODSP`

what I want to achieve is

`No.SKF.2164-02A/2020/CBO-ODSP`

but there are data that

```
No.SKF.4-04/2021/CBO-ODSP
No.SKF.233-04/2021/CBO-ODSP
```

the query

```
SELECT *, 
       concat("left"("NO_SURAT", 13), CHR(64 + CAST ( row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY "ACCOUNT_NUMBER" order by "ACCOUNT_NUMBER") AS integer )), "right"("NO_SURAT", 14)) AS No_suratpart 
from "account_information"
```

the length of the word is varied because it generated

what I want to achieve is the data to look like this

```
No.SKF.2164-02A/2020/CBO-ODSP
No.SKF.4-04A/2021/CBO-ODSP
No.SKF.233-04A/2021/CBO-ODSP
```

is this there any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample data indicates you want to insert just before the first '/'. If this rule holds true then you can separate, insert the char and recombine at that point. Try the following:

```
with test_stg ( stg_val) as 
     (values ('No.SKF.2164-02/2020/CBO-ODSP')
           , ('No.SKF.4-04/2021/CBO-ODSP')
           , ('No.SKF.233-04/2021/CBO-ODSP')
     )
select concat(  left(stg_val, position('/' in stg_val ) - 1)
              , 'A'
              , right(stg_val, length(stg_val) - position('/' in stg_val )+1) 
              )
  from test_stg ;
```